# How to rename infoplist.strings file?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ios, localization, target

Is it possible to use other names for **infoplist.strings** file?
My problem: I want to create more than one target with different localized app names.

Answer (score 2):

You just create localized version of the same file.  [image: See my screen shot.] And in there you set the name for each language for CFBundleDisplayName.

For example:
In the english file:
CFBundleDisplayName = "English name of the app"

In the French file:
CFBundleDisplayName = "French name of the app"

iOS will load the proper localization file.  And if a language is missing it will use the default language in the info.plist.  In my case, it en.

Comment: that's the first part of the deal. But how do I assign different CFBundleDisplayNames to different targets?

Comment: You don't have to create individual target for each language.

Comment: But I have to (for another reason). And each target gets its own app name

Comment: So for example you have a French target and a English target? Or whatever other language you want?

Comment: For ex 2 targets with 2 languages: english target 1, english target 2, german target 1, german target 2. Each target has it's own localized name.

Comment: What reason do you have for doing it this way? Because Xcode has great abilities to localized apps.  And when iOS loads the app it will load/use the proper localized information.

Comment: I think I don't doing anything "wrong way" here. I just need more than 1 target (for many other reasons). And I'm curios why it's not possible to use other names for infoplist.strings file.

Answer (score 2):

I've had what sounds like the same issue.  I'm building two different apps from the same files, just with two different XCode projects, but the InfoPlist.strings files need to be different as they contain the name of the app. A simple solution I found is to use two separate folders inside of which your localized infoplist.strings are. For example:

```
+Version_A
  +en.lproj
     InfoPlist.strings
  +fr.lproj
     InfoPlist.strings
+Version_B
  +en.lproj
     InfoPlist.strings
  +fr.lproj
     InfoPlist.strings
```

Then in each XCode project you simply include the one relevant location (Version_A or Version_B) and not the other. If you do that too, check that the Copy Bundle Resources under your Build Phases pick the correct version (you can click Show in Finder from there).

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"key", @"myStringsFile", @"comment");
```

where you can specify the name of the .strings file which you can then make dependent on the target.

Comment: But AFAIK it's possible to localize the app name only in a file named "infoplist.strings". Isn't it?..